# Creating Mega Menu in kentico where tree structure is different than what new menu requires

Tags: navigation, kentico, megamenu

I am trying to create a new mega menu for an existing website the problem is the new mega menu does not reflect how the website content is structure in the CMS Tree.

Currently I have played around with the idea of creating a custom table with fields like
`MenuTitle, Link, Display, Parent, MenuOrder`
and use that with a  repeater to create the menu but this seems like a bad idea for anyone who will want to make an change to menu structure.

Is there any other way I can do this in kentico ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest creating a separate folder structure with a new page type with the following fields:

MenuDisplayName
MenuURL
MenuTarget

This will then allow you to build your site navigation independent of your content tree.